# What can I do about a bad question I asked after I have got an answer?

Tags: support, questions, answered-questions

Sometimes I ask a question for which the answer is very straightforward, and I missed the solution which is very obvious. I know that I can't delete a question after I got an answer. Is there something I can do about it (like recommending closing) or something like that?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can still delete a question with a single answer which has not be upvoted or accepted.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: You can, though sometimes, perhaps mostly, you oughtn't to; and the question may well be undeleted in response to flags.

Answer (score 16):

Leave it open.  If you missed the obvious solution, there's a very good chance that someone else will, too.

Comment: Indeed. Often solutions look obvious in retrospect - but only in retrospect. Beating oneself up over that is an occupational hazard in mathematics.

Answer (score 8):

> Sometimes I ask a question for which the answer is very straightforward, and I missed the solution which is very obvious.

That's not necessarily a problem. If the question is on-topic for the Stack Exchange site you posted it on, it doesn't really matter if it's 'easy' or 'hard'. Yes, you might get downvotes because users *suspect* lack of research - that's why you should always try to show what you've done / what you do know about the question.

Some sites in the network, like Stack Overflow, do have a close reason that might be applicable:

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before posting.

The 'simple typographical error' is such a problem with a straightforward solution, so in that case voting to close the question might be in order. But most sites don't have this.